# Concrete 5 Global Variables on Single Pages

Tags: php, scope, concrete5

```
<?php
$productsInc="products_export.php";

function productsUrl($category){
    global $accountNumber, $accountPassword, $productsInc; 
    echo "file is " . $productsInc;
}
?>
```

When this page is run by itself it echos "file is prodcuts_export.php",
But when it is run as a "Single_Page" within Concrete5,
It echos "file is " and also has no errors

Comment: And to preempt... It's not hiding somewhere in the layout. It's not there at all, source or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this onto that PHP file vairable

```
$productsInc="/themes/YOURTHEMENAME/products_export.php";
```

Thats with me guessing that your products_export php file is not within any child directories and is placed with your default file.

Hope this sorts it for you!

Comment: Good thought. Concrete 5 does cause some confusion (IMO) with the directory references... But in this case ignore that it's a file at all. I can't echo the STRING('products_export.php'). If the string is just "Hello World" I still can't echo it, despite declaring it as global.